# Apostrophes in Html and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, apostrophe

how can I write this string correctly?

```
tr = tr + '<tr onclick="localStorage.setItem("X", ' + xVal + '); document.location = "page.html";"></tr>'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use inline event handler attributes and you won't have problems with apostrophes.

Comment: @Bergi How can I do?

Comment: Use the DOM to create your elements, instead of building HTML strings, and then [register your event handlers](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) as functions (not strings), so that you can use a closure over `xVal`.

Answer (score -2):

Dont know what you want to achieve but you can use backslash \ for special characters

```
tr = tr + '<tr onclick="localStorage.setItem("X", ' + xVal + ');document.location = \"page.html\";"></tr>'
```

my bad below is correct.. onclick should be escaped in single quotes to work

```
tr = tr + '<tr onclick=\'localStorage.setItem("X", "' + xVal + '"); document.location = "page.html";\'></tr>'
```

Comment: No need to escape quotes in an apostrophe-delimited string.

Comment: This will create exactly the same string that OP is already creating.

Comment: onclick needs to be escaped in single quote also the storage value need to be put in double quotes [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aasiph/gmd2z7ru/).

in your case if it is array of table rows you may also need to set the id of the local storage accordingly